# Can a hit and trial matrix take place in a recursive function without creating multiple copies?

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking

I have a matrix which needs to be changed by hit and trial method, evaluated and the values need to be re-assigned if it does not meet the requirements. I am doing this in a recursive function for chained assumption. Can this be done without creating multiple copies?

Can I restore the matrix while backtracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask: "Can I restore the matrix while backtracking?" I ask the same question - can you? If the modifications are easily reversible, then sure you can.

```
void f()
{
    foreach (possibilty)
        modify ();
        f();
        unmodify();  
}
```

If unmodify is not trivial, then you'd be better off with

```
void f(matrix m)
{
   foreach (possibilty)
        matrix tmp = m;
        modify (tmp);
        f(tmp);
}
```

Comment: therefore i'll need a copy for each depth of assumption. thanks!

Comment: Creating copies is much simpler to handle for maintenance concerns, in my experience.